# for loop array length

Tags: javascript

```
var stack = new Array();
var ii = 0;

function pushTutor(item) {
var jj = stack.length;
    for(ii=0;ii<jj;ii++) {
        stack.push(item);
        alert(stack);
    }
}
```

I remember the stack.length cause the issue which is not able to loop at all. What is the solution for this?

Comment: What do you want to do? Why the loop?

Comment: What's the problem for which's solution you're asking?

Comment: this is strange indeed : for each element in stack you add the same item, stack = [a,b,c] pushTutor(d) will give [a,b,c,d,d,d] I guess.

Comment: I assume that your goal is to insert the item in the end of the array? So `push` does exactly this, no need for loop at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, aside from the fact that you don't need a `for` loop for what you're trying to achieve here, `stack` has no items, so its length is 0. As such, your loop will never execute.

If you just want to push the item, surely it'd be better to do:

```
function pushTutor(item)
{
    stack.push(item);
    alert(stack.length);
    // Alerting stack here would simply alert 'array'
}
```

Comment: After you push, it should alert item and then item,item next time

Answer (score 1):

The code does not make sense.

Perhaps you want

```
var stack = new Array();

function pushTutor(item) {
  stack.push(item);
  alert(stack);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stack is empty, that's a problem.